# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$1

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

When I try to run my main project I get this error:

[2015-04-20 17:32:11 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$1;
[2015-04-20 17:32:11 - OrangesToOranges] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$1;

Here are the library files for each project folder:

[image][image][image]

Here are the build path screenshots:

facebook:

[image]
[image]!

main project:

[image]!
[image]!

android-support-v7-appcompat:

[image][image]

BTW, I tried unchecking all of the Android Private Library and Android Dependencies libraries, and the same error came up.

I have tried cleaning the projects and also restarting Eclipse.

Comment: the two sets of bolts in orangestooranges seems dodgy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted all the bin folders, then ran Clean and then Build. Restarted Eclipse. 
**Unchecked the contents of Android Private Libraries and checked Android Private Libraries of each project.** This solved the issue. This solution was mentioned in a related post on stack overflow though it was one of many.